# Nuxtjs Google Auth

Tags: google-oauth, nuxt.js

After calling $auth.loginWith('google'), I am getting 
http://localhost:3000/ru/user-registration#state=D7xooLsNNxNGfbvcQMU5g&access_token=ya29.a0Ae4lvC2z0XERgeRUipmu7c205WWCCSVgRZ-s_mYWg6ZoMgCGzVZ-U69arfpn-ybm5kthqtvqQrD7lGYmNDqiLtkW1aIecP6Wp-bwINMok3ztNcW5KwmlohLmtnbk4IZVkciKfb8T_JUtf89xpJcjpt2dSx_09FPGSKc&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=email%20profile%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=consent as a callback. What should I do next in order to get the info of the registered gmail. Any help or ideas are welcome

auth part in my  nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: "token/", method: "post", propertyName: "access" },
      user: { url: "user/me/", method: "get", propertyName: false },
      logout: false,
    }
  },
  google: {
    client_id: 'my_client_id',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  }
},
```

},

Comment: Could you share your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: Hi. I have attached it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `nuxt.config.js` file you declare two differents strategies: local and google. If you would like to use Google as an identity provider you don't need to precise the endpoints.

Here is my actual config for one of my project:

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/login',
    home: '/',
    callback: '/callback'
  },
  strategies: {
    google: {
      client_id: 'XXXXXxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    }
  }
}
```

And I have specified on Google API Console the following authorized URI: `localhost:3000/callback` for my dev environment and `mydomain.com/callback` for the prod.

Comment: Thank you for you effort and reply. I am wondering that should I do something with the callback response which comes in my url after I log in or google takes care of it ,itself? Because I am having the same structure and after response is returned in my url, it is doing nothing.

Comment: This looks like the same error I got few weeks ago. What is the version of Auth module you are using?

Comment: "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.8.5",

Comment: Try to run this command `npm install @nuxtjs/auth@latest`. I'm pretty sure that will solve your issue :)

Comment: Good morning . Thanks brother for your effort and help. Unfortunately I couldn't, and we preferred to do it in the backend rather than front end. Now , it works )